# How to connect Two Database MySQL and MongoDB in the same project? Is it possible?

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

Currently I'm using Hibernate(MySQL) with Spring, the configuration is running fine for me, but once I configured another configuration mongo-config.xml file and trying to run a test case with mongodb it's **showing Error creating bean with name ....** from first configuration.

**Below is my mongo-config.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.mongo" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mongo-dao.properties" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />

</bean>
<bean id="mongoDbFactory" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${spring.datasource.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="host" value="${spring.data.mongodb.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${spring.data.mongodb.port}" />
    <property name="databaseName" value="${spring.data.mongodb.database}" />
```

**and my first configuration for hibernate is looks like something**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hb.dao" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.hb..dao.domain.entity</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql:false}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql:false}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

**And the stack trace is**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
```

***Caused by:  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accessProfileDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.soe.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.*** 
Dependency annotations:

**Here is my test Class-**

```
    public class MongoQuestionsTest extends BaseDaoMongoTest{   
        private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MongoQuestionsTest.class);

        @Autowired
        private MongoTestDao mongoTestDaoImpl;
        @Test
        public void saveQuestions(){
            MongoQuestions mongoQuestions = new MongoQuestions();
            mongoQuestions.setUsername("Hi");
            mongoQuestions.setPassword("Hello");
            mongoTestDaoImpl.save(mongoQuestions);
            logger.debug("Mongo User Set with id " + mongoQuestions.getId());
        }
    and **BaseDaoMongoTest**---

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/mongo-config-test.xml"})
    public class BaseDaoMongoTest {
    }
```

And in MongoTestDaoImpl class I just Auto-wired MongoTemplate and calling save() method that's it.

Comment: How are you trying to load the Spring configuration xmls in your test case.? Could u paste your test class.?

Comment: @PraneethRamesh question Edited have a look..thanks

Comment: Did you create two entity connections for two different databases?

Comment: @harshavmb sir actually i'm new in spring & hibernate, so i'm little bit confuse about your question, but as i understand, you are asking for 'One different entity Class for both the Databases' and yes i did the same but if i'm not right please correct me about--"two entity connections for two different databases?"

Comment: Yes, create two database configuration classes, one for mysql and the other one for mongo. Easiest way to do this is to create two different packages and use `ComponentScan` annotation for each database configuration class. I too had this problem and I resolved. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077095/springboot-always-read-data-from-primary-datasource for more details

Comment: @harshavmb as you can see i'm using XML configuration to configure databases so i don't think to create configuration classes for it and i did the same as you said for packages and ComponentScan in xml.

Comment: @CreatedBylucky, have done this configuration using springboot and its working for me. Will add this an answer.

Comment: @harshavmb, i haven't done this using spring Boot. If you have configuration file working for you can you give me code snippet or GitHub Demo file. Thanks

Comment: @CreatedBylucky, have added the code to github now. Feel free to try and let me know if it works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is the best solution. But, it worked for me. 
If you have two relational databases using `Jpa` module, then I would suggest you to create `entity` and `transaction` manager beans to read each datasource config. Refer the below link for the above use case.

[springboot always read data from primary datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077095/springboot-always-read-data-from-primary-datasource)

As you wish to have a combination of `SQL` and `NoSQL`, I would create `entity` and `transcation` manager beans for `MySQL` database as it works well with `Jpa`. And leave as-is configuration for `Mongo`(configs read directly from `application.properties`).

**`MySQLConfiguration` datasource config class :**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-multiple-db.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.springdata.dao.mysql", entityManagerFactoryRef = "mysqlEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "mysqlTransactionManager")
public class MySQLConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(myMySQLDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.springdata.models" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource myMySQLDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.mysql.jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.mysql.jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.mysql.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.mysql.pass"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(mysqlEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

Above datasource config params are read from `classpath:persistence-multiple-db.properties` file in the classpath.

```
# mysql jdbc connections
spring.mysql.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.mysql.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.mysql.user=root
spring.mysql.pass=password1

# hibernate.X
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

The above configuration, should be suffice to deal `MySQL` datasource. To have mongo configuration in your project, add the below lines to `application.properties`.

```
# mongo configuration
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
```

Springboot will automatically create the necessary mongo datasource beans and keeps them readily available for spring container to use.

Now, create repository interfaces for both MySQL and Mongo datasources.

**`MyMongoRepository` interface:**

```
@Transactional
public interface MyMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<Users, String>{

}
```

**`MySQLRepository` interface:**

```
@Transactional
public interface MySQLRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, String>{

}
```

**`Users` pojo class :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Document(collection="users")
@Data
public class Users {

    @Id
    @javax.persistence.Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

}
```

Have added below annotations to enable mongorepositoreis and for component scan to springboot main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.springdata" })
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages={"com.springdata.dao.mongo"})
public class SpringbootmysqlmongoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootmysqlmongoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Finally, some code to test.

**`MyRepositoryImpl` class:**

```
@Service
public class MyRepositoryImpl {

    @Autowired
    private MyMongoRepository myMongoRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MySQLRepository mySQLRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void extractUsers(){
        myMongoRepository.findAll().forEach((user) -> System.out.println("user name from mongo is : "+user.getName()));
        mySQLRepository.findAll().forEach((user) -> System.out.println("User name from mysql is : "+user.getName()));
    }

}
```

Have created `users` table in `mysql test` database and `users` collection in `mongo test` database.

Lastly, have uploaded my code to git repository.

https://github.com/harshavmb/springbootmysqlmongo